# Saving Table from website results in more data then displayed on the page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

I'm fairy new to nightmare.js and js overall but I'm trying to save a table from a site [Table View Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Fhz.png) but it seems that its also saving the 'greyed' out data which is probably for other devices (mobiles) or something. Is there any way to ignore these or set a device that it only sees the data for the device?

```
const Nightmare1 = require('nightmare');
var fs = require('fs');
var nightmare = Nightmare1({
show: true
});
const selector = 'table.table-striped:nth-child(1)';
nightmare
.goto(siteURL)
.evaluate(selector => {
    return document.querySelector(selector).outerHTML;
}, selector)
.then(function (page) {
    fs.writeFile('body.html', page, function (err) {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        console.log('writing done');
    })
})
.catch(function () {
    console.log('caught', arguments);
});
```

Comment: It is normal that the script gets the greyed out items, they are most likely just greyed out in your source view browser to show that they are hidden using CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding rows that contain a class that you don't want to be picked up by your 
script.

So if you don't want a row with `visibility-tiny` class to be picked up, do this:

`table.table-striped:nth-child(1):not(.visability-tiny)`